# Left join does not meet my requirement

Tags: mysql

There are two tables over here: first is for basic details of "poll" and
second for the "answer". My requirement is like this:

> **i want poll records to display only for users who didn't answer the poll**

I tried this query but it is not working:

```
select p.* from mycom_poll as p 
    LEFT JOIN mycom_polls_result as pr on (p.b_id != pr.b_poll_id
        And pr.b_user_id !=14) where p.v_status = 'enable' 
                And p.v_country like '%India%'
                AND p.d_activate_date <= '2015-04-17' order by p.b_id limit 1"

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mycom_poll` (
      `b_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `b_user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `v_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `v_question` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
      `v_country` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `d_activate_date` date NOT NULL,
      `dt_created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
      `dt_updated_date` datetime NOT NULL,
      `v_ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `v_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'enable',
      PRIMARY KEY (`b_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

    INSERT INTO `mycom_poll` (`b_id`, `b_user_id`, `v_code`, `v_question`, `v_country`, `d_activate_date`, `dt_created_date`, `dt_updated_date`, `v_ip`, `v_status`) VALUES(8, 0, '20150417115406-192168113C5ZJpXu2hM', 'Who is chief minstor of Gujarat in 2015 Rajyasabha?', '["Global","India","United States"]', '2015-04-15', '2015-04-17 11:56:12', '2015-04-18 07:29:11', '127.0.0.1', 'enable');

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mycom_polls_result` (
      `b_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `b_poll_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
      `b_user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
      `b_poll_answer` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
      `dt_created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
      `dt_updated_date` datetime NOT NULL,
      `v_ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `v_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'enable',
      PRIMARY KEY (`b_id`),
      KEY `b_poll_id` (`b_poll_id`,`b_user_id`),
      KEY `b_poll_id_2` (`b_poll_id`,`b_user_id`,`b_poll_answer`),
      KEY `b_poll_id_3` (`b_poll_id`,`b_user_id`,`b_poll_answer`),
      KEY `b_user_id` (`b_user_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

    INSERT INTO `mycom_polls_result` (`b_id`, `b_poll_id`, `b_user_id`, `b_poll_answer`, `dt_created_date`, `dt_updated_date`, `v_ip`, `v_status`) VALUES
    (1, 8, 14, 64, '2015-04-18 13:27:50', '2015-04-18 13:27:50', '127.0.0.1', 'enable');
```

Comment: Hint:  Use a `left join` and then have `where <something> is null`.

Comment: you mean like that but its not working  select p.* from mycom_poll as p 
    Left JOIN mycom_polls_result as pr on p.b_id != pr.b_poll_id AND pr.b_user_id !=14 where p.v_status = 'enable' And p.v_country like '%India%'
                AND p.d_activate_date <= '2015-04-17' And pr.b_id is null
                order by p.b_id

Comment: if record found on poll_resuilt  for b_user_id = 14 and poll_id = 8 every time record poll record display for that user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query:

```
select p.* from mycom_poll as p 
        LEFT JOIN mycom_polls_result as pr on (p.b_id != pr.b_poll_id
            And pr.b_user_id !=14) where p.v_status = 'enable' 
                    And p.v_country like '%India%'
                    AND p.d_activate_date <= '2015-04-17' order by p.b_id limit 1
```

First I am going to point out the mistake of this query, what you are doing here is, you are left joining two tables on **id of first table not equals to id of second table** which will join all the table data whose ids are not same, when you do a left join, you always get the data of left table and if data not present in right table you get null.

So in **where clause** you should check any if the field of second table is null or not like this.

```
select p.* from mycom_poll as p 
    LEFT JOIN mycom_polls_result as pr on p.b_id = pr.b_poll_id
    where pr.b_user_id !=14 p.v_status = 'enable' 
    And p.v_country like '%India%' AND p.d_activate_date <= '2015-04-17'
    and pr.b_poll_id is null order by p.b_id limit 1
```

I request you to understand [left join](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php) first.

Comment: thanks gordan i done it you right  "only i have to found secound table field is null  it means secound table does not have match on first table"

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are using `LEFT JOIN` which is correct to force all rows of the `mycom_poll` table to be considered, but you're joining on `p.b_id != pr.b_poll_id` which will associate each poll row in `mycom_poll` with all the unrelated results rows in `mycom_polls_result` that don't belong to it.
You probably need to join on `p.b_id = pr.b_poll_id`, and then require rows with `pr.b_poll_id IS NULL` in your `WHERE` clause. 
You also seem to be trying to restrict results to `pr.b_user_id !=14`, which is fine, but that needs to be stated along with other filtering conditions in the `WHERE` clause. The `LEFT JOIN ON` clause is just going to be used to declare the column relationships between your tables.

```
    SELECT p.*
     FROM mycom_poll as p 
     LEFT JOIN mycom_polls_result as pr
     ON p.b_id = pr.b_poll_id
    WHERE
     pr.b_user_id !=14
     AND p.v_status = 'enable' 
     AND p.v_country like '%India%'
     AND p.d_activate_date <= '2015-04-17' 
     AND pr.b_poll_id IS NULL
    ORDER BY p.b_id LIMIT 1
```

HTH